# How to make a inset box-shadow inside a table that renders over images

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to to make the box-shadow effect render over all the elements inside the table.
Here is closest I could get to what I want:

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}

table{


  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #aaa;

  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  
}



img{
margin: 10px;  


}
```

```html
<body>


<table>

<tr><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td></tr>


</table>

</body>
```

Reading multiple questions on stackoverflow, I discovered the best way to do that would be creating a div or a pseudo element before the end of the container (in this case, the table) and apply the effect to it.
But when I try to do that, I end up overshooting/overflowing the container.
I tried changing multiple parameters for both elements (container and div) with no success.
In the next code snippet, the shadow is green and the borders of the table are red for debugging purposes.

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}

table{
  border:2px solid red ;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #aaa;
  border-radius:5px;
}

#boxShadow{
  
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 20px 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);

}

img{
margin: 10px;  

}
```

```html
<body>

<table>
<tr><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td></tr>
<div id="boxShadow"></div>
</table>

</body>
```

The code is also here in jsfiddle.com:
http://jsfiddle.net/h0rf42m7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work properly by creating a new div to contain the table:

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}

table{
  position: relative;
  background: #aaa;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container{
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

#boxShadow{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  
}

img{
margin: 10px;  

}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="container">

<table border = 1>
<tr><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td><td><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*VU152GltXiWeD0Xy.png" height=20%></td></tr>
</table>
<div id="boxShadow">
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Beautiful effect!